# jQuery, get click on frame B from within frame A

Tags: jquery, iframe, click

I have several frames on my parent document. From within frame A I would like to detect a click on frame B with id="frameB".

I think I need to access the parent document first. I can get detect a click on the parent document with:

```
$(parent.document).click(function(){});
```

But I don't know how to get frameB in particular.

Comment: Does the frame have an ID?  Can you use something like $(parent.document).('#iFrameID').click(function(){});     My syntax might be off...  this isn't tested.   Seems correct though.

Comment: These are all on the same domain right?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like

```
$(parent.document).find('#frameB').contents().find('body').on('click', function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted  a text box to do something that resides in FrameA, why not just bind the FrameB object to the click event, then trigger the event "click" on the element in framA